# How to change syntax highlighting of JSX Component tags with Textmate in VSCODE?

Tags: components, jsx, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I couldn't find any documentation on syntax highlighting jsx Component tags. For example I want to make  bold and  a separate concern.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "punctuation.definition.tag",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#5452529f",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: *** For example I want to make <Component /> bold, and syntax-highlighting of <div/> a separate concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these scopes:

```
  {
    "scope": [
      "support.class.component.open.jsx", // JSX Component
      "support.class.component.close.jsx",
    ],
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#20d397",
      "fontStyle": "bold"
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": [
      "entity.name.tag.open.jsx", // Regular JSX/HTML tag
      "entity.name.tag.close.jsx"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#d32082",
    }
  },
```

I have used contrasted colors so you can see the results below:
[image]